# How to enable IPV6 packet capturing in WireShark at the same time as IPV4?

Tags: networking, ipv6, wireshark, packet-analyzer, ipv4

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and for some debugging work need to capture IPV6 packets going to and from a specific port, however I understand that by default IPV6 packets are not captured by WireShark, so how can I get WireShark to capture them? And can I also get it to capture both IPV4 and IPV6 packets? I have read [this](https://wiki.wireshark.org/IPv6), however this does not seem to explain how to show both IPV6 and IPV4 packets at the same time, only how to filter it so that it only shows IPV6 ones.

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

**Package Information:**

```
wireshark:
  Installed: 1.12.7+g7fc8978-1
  Candidate: 1.12.7+g7fc8978-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.12.7+g7fc8978-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: So what did you do or not do as listed here - https://wiki.wireshark.org/IPv6

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: Are you using ipv6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, there is nothing that you need to do. Simply select the appropriate interface to capture on, and start capturing. *All* traffic on that interface will be captured.

To show only ipv6 traffic in the display, you simply enter *ipv6* as the filter match.

Answer (score 0):

> however I understand that by default IPV6 packets are not captured by WireShark

There is nothing in Wireshark to, by default, *not* capture IPv6 packets.  Just try capturing them.